# First variation --- A differentiation problem.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

[image]

**My question:**

This is just differentiation and I did it. I got $$T'(\epsilon)[L(T(\epsilon),x(T(\epsilon);\epsilon),\dot x(T(\epsilon);\epsilon))]+\int_0^{T(\epsilon)}L_x(t,x(t,\epsilon),\dot x(t,\epsilon))\frac{\partial x(t,\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}dt+\int_0^{T(\epsilon)}L_{\dot x}(t,x(t,\epsilon),\dot x(t,\epsilon))\frac{\partial \dot x(t,\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}dt$$
at $\epsilon=0$.

Since the result should be represented by $\tau$, $\xi$ and $\eta$.

So I just naively think the result is $$\tau L(T^*, x^*(T^*),\dot x^*(T^*))+\int_0^{T^*}L_x(t,x^*(t),\dot x^*(t)) \eta dt+\int_0^{T^*}L_{\dot x}(t,x^*(t),\dot x^*(t) )\frac{\partial \dot x(t,\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}dt|_{\epsilon =0}$$
But in my result there is no $\xi$!
Where am I wrong? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The last term in your second integral is $\xi$, isn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hi, do you mean $\frac{\partial \dot x(t,\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}$ is $\xi$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant your *first* integral. Look at how $\xi$ is defined, and remember that there's an evaluation at $\epsilon=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hi, Gerry. I edited the question. Can you explain why $\xi$ is the first integral and how to simplify the second integral? Where am I wrong? Thanks so much! :)